configuration queryparameters in Branch.io
this is a part of backend code:
        $query_parameters = [
        'item_id' => $id,
        'item_name='.$item_name
    ];
    $query_setting = http_build_query($query_parameters);

    $fullUrl = $CI->Backend_config->get_one('be1')->branch_domain_url.$item_name.'?'.$query_setting;


  

    $payload = json_encode([
        'branch_key'=> $key,
        'campaign' => $title,
        'stage' => $id,
        'data' => [
            '$desktop_url'=> $CI->Backend_config->get_one('be1')->dyn_web_url,
            '$ios_url'=> $CI->Backend_config->get_one('be1')->dyn_ios_url,
            '$ipad_url'=> $CI->Backend_config->get_one('be1')->dyn_ios_url,
            '$android_url'=> $CI->Backend_config->get_one('be1')->dyn_android_url,
            '$og_title'=> $title,
            '$og_description'=> $description,
            '$og_image_url' => $img,
            '$canonical_url' => $fullUrl,
            ]
        ]);

and this is flutter code:
I want to extract item_id in queryparametrs but it can not implement:
    _linkSubscription = _appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen(
  (Uri uri) async {
    print('onAppLink: $uri');

    if (uri.queryParameters.isNotEmpty) {
      final Map<String, String> queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
      if (queryParams.isNotEmpty) {
        itemId = queryParams['item_id'];
        print(itemId);
      }
    });

in the results I can not see item_Id in queryparametrs:

